# Loop j always fetch previous response , not fetching the latest one

Tags: android, loopj

**I use Loop j for fetching data from server in my app. But it always fetch the old response . I test my api on postman and gets the latest response from server.
If any one know how to clear the loop j old response from cache?**

**Here is my code**

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

```
    client.get("http://bnailsusa.com/app_api/getView.php?serviceprovider", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {



            Log.d("Tag:", String.valueOf(response));


            try {
                for (int i=0;i<=response.length();i++){


                    //region Fetching
                    JSONObject index=response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name=index.getString("Name");
                    String spid=index.getString("spid");
                    String Photo=index.getString("PHOTO");
                    //endregion

                    //region Storing
                    names.add(name);
                    SPID.add(spid);
                    images.add(Photo);
                    Log.d("Tag:ar", String.valueOf(names));
                    //endregion

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            ProvidersAdapter booksAdapter = new ProvidersAdapter(SelectServiceProvider.this, names,images);
            gridView.setAdapter(booksAdapter);
        }
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.mime.Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse){


        }
    });
```

Comment: you need make POJO for web service..

Comment: Can you give some example for fetching my api.

Comment: where is json array key in json?